# How to use an array for a method within a loop

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I am using a list of URLs within a loop for a test in Selenium. For each specific URL I want to define separate strings for a reusable method I'm calling within the test. They all have to be different or else my data will overwrite each other.

```
public class LogIn extends ReusableMethod {

// here is my lists of URLS

@Test void test()throws Exception {

     String[] Urls;
     Urls = new String[3];

     Urls[0] = "site.com/us/en";
     Urls[1] = "site.com/ca/en";
     Urls[2] = "site.com/au/en";


     for (int i=0; i<Urls.length; i++) {
         openbrowser(Urls[i]);

     //openbrowser is calling a reusable method to open a browser and go to 
     each //URL and the test loops through the URLs defined above



  //------- sign in from the sign in page--------//
     RegisteredSignIn();

     CheckTitle();

// My check title method calls 
/*
public void CheckTitle () {
    String ActualTitle = driver.getTitle();


String[]  Title = new String[7];

    Title[0] = "My Site Account | Site US";
    Title[1] = "My Site Account | Site CA";
    Title[2] = "My Site Account | Site AU";

    for (int i=0; i<Title.length; i++) {

    if(ActualTitle.equals(Title[i])){
        System.out.println("Page"+ Title[i] + " is up + Registered Log on 
have passed");
    }
    else {System.err.println( Title[i] + " Page + Registerd Log on have 
FAILED");   
    }
    }
}*/


      quitbrowser();

    }

}   
}
```

I can get the single title of a page and compare it to the expected title.. but how do I change the string used within the method and loop it as well to keep changing with my Test loop?

Comment: This formatting hurts me soul. Please, in the future, format your code. I tried and couldn't do it properly

Comment: @ThatBraziliann, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your post lends one to think that you are very new to software development. It feels like some missing some basic knowledge. I'd recommend some reading on [Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp) so as to understand how a method can be self-contained (reusable). Follow it up with [Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp) and [Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_attributes.asp). I think that will give you the framework necessary to fix your issue.

Comment: @ThatBraziliann, many StackOverflow users will take more kindly to future questions when proper coding conventions are used; while Google isn't the standards king, they have a well documented [style-guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4-formatting) that is followed by many developers.

Comment: @Wheeler Thanks for all The info. I will definitely take a look into it and read about everything you mentioned. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but it sounds like you need to store your expected titles in a similar way to how you store the URLs you need to test. Here's an example:

```java
public class LogIn {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        String[] urls = new String[3];

        urls[0] = "site.com/us/en";
        urls[1] = "site.com/ca/en";
        urls[2] = "site.com/au/en";

        String[] titles = new String[3];
        titles[0] = "Site Title - US";
        titles[1] = "Site Title - CA";
        titles[2] = "Site Title - AU";

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            checkTitle(urls[i], titles[i]);
        }
    }

    void checkTitle(String url, String expected) {
        openbrowser(url);

        //------- sign in from the sign in page--------//
        RegisteredSignIn();

        CheckTitle(expected);

        quitbrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ordonezalex 
public class LogIn extends ReusableMethod { 
  
 Test void test()throws Exception {
  
   String[] Urls;
   Urls = new String[3];

      Urls[0] = "https://www.nixon.com/us/en";
      Urls[1] = "https://www.nixon.com/ca/en";
      
      String[] Titles;
      Titles = new String[3];
      Titles[0] = "My Nixon Account | Nixon US";
      Titles[1] = "My Nixon Account | Nixon CA";
     
 for (int i=0; i<Urls.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(Urls.length);
     openbrowser(Urls[i]);
       RegisteredSignIn();
       CheckTitle(Titles[i]); ....

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap whole method to accept single argument - url - and than in test case iterate over your urls.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ordonezalex  I used your solution like soo..

```
public class LogIn extends ReusableMethod { 

    Test void test()throws Exception {

     String[] Urls;
     Urls = new String[3];

        Urls[0] = "https://www.nixon.com/us/en";
        Urls[1] = "https://www.nixon.com/ca/en";

        String[] Titles;
        Titles = new String[3];
        Titles[0] = "My Nixon Account | Nixon US";
        Titles[1] = "My Nixon Account | Nixon CA";

     for (int i=0; i<Urls.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Urls.length);

        openbrowser(Urls[i]);

        RegisteredSignIn();

        CheckTitle(Titles[i]); ....
```

Comment: Hi @ThatBraziliann, I'm glad you found a solution! For future questions, please take a look at a popular Java style guide, [such as Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). Using a popular and consistent style will help you receive better answers on stackoverflow